# "There's a missing page" vs. "there's a page missing"

Tags: word-order, present-participles

Sometimes we see the adjective "missing" used before nouns and sometimes after nouns. What is the difference in usage in this regard? For example:

> - There is a missing page in the book.
> - There is a page missing in this book.

What is the difference between these sentences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grammatical difference is that, in the first, *missing* is an adjective, but, in the second, it is a non-finite verb. There is little if any semantic difference, but it is possible that in some contexts a writer might decide that one is more appropriate than the other.

Those of a logical turn of mind might insist that a page that is missing cannot actually be **IN** a book, and that the only way of expressing the idea is to write ‘There is a page missing **FROM** this book.’

Comment: Might not the first example imply that a page, missing from some other book, is caught in this book?

Comment: It might, but I can't say I've ever found one.